# Getting null at the end of json output

Tags: javascript, json, magento-1.9

Here is my code:-

```html
 try
        {
            $cur_category = array();
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
            $tree = $category->getTreeModel();
            $tree->load();
            $ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
            if ($ids)
            {
                foreach ($ids as $id)
                {
                    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
                    $cat->load($id);
                    $node["category_id"] = $cat->getId();
                    $node["name"] = $cat->getName();
                    $node["image_url"] = $cat->getImageUrl();
                    $cur_category[] = $node;

                }
                
            }

            echo json_encode($cur_category); 
        }catch (Exception $e){
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "500", "error" => $message));
        }
```

The output of the code is :-

```html
[{"category_id":"1","name":"Root Catalog","image_url":false},{"category_id":"2","name":"Electronics","image_url":"http:\/\/localhost:81\/magento\/media\/catalog\/category\/Apple-MGX92HN-A-MacBook-Pro-SDL150017386-1-c0afa.jpg"},{"category_id":"3","name":"Laptops","image_url":false},{"category_id":"4","name":"Men","image_url":false},{"category_id":"5","name":"Women","image_url":false},{"category_id":"6","name":"Baby & Kids","image_url":false},{"category_id":"7","name":"Home & Furniture","image_url":false},{"category_id":"8","name":"Accessories","image_url":false},{"category_id":"9","name":"Formal Mens Jeans","image_url":false}]null
```

The problem is at the end as you can see null is coming how to remove it any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you have all your data at json object inside brackets [ ]?
So if there is nothing missing. I suggest just parse your return string from `json_encode($cur_category)`. For quick look I think your `$cur_category` does have an empty [ ] row in the end and so returning `null`

My main point is use parsing to your result string and just make sure that your `$cur_category` does not have empty rows.

Cat your array by using

```
echo(print_f($cur_category,true));
```

Comment: Well Leo its an rest api which i have made, echo json_encode($cur_category); on printing this i get null, can you please tell me how can i parse it here in same php function.

Comment: For this concept now you know your result string format. You can use `str_replace()` to replace null to ''  get desired result.

Comment: Suppose if I send this output to android and they do json parsing then what do you think will they get data proper.

Comment: Now I can't fully answer this question if your php script doesn't get all data inside those [ ] brackets. I assume that you get full data.
What I have done usually is to send this JSON data by just one string and use Gson library at Android side to parse the data straight to my desired custom object.
[link](https://github.com/google/gson) Github
[link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) tutorial
Hope this helps and if my answer is acceptable please accept it. :)